# JQuery not showing next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code is:

```
var run = function(){
    $(".fade#f1").delay(0).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f2").delay(2000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f1").delay(4000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f2").delay(4500).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f3").delay(8000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f4").delay(9000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f3").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f4").delay(5500).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f5").delay(16000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f6").delay(17000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f5").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f6").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() { run() }); 
};
```

The first image loads perfectly fine but the second, third and fourth images don't appear. Have I wrote the code wrong?

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is make photos seem like they are overlapped. When the first image fades in it will remain for a while and then fade out and the other one will be right there behind it.

Comment: create a fiddle question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

The main problem might be, effects and animations does not wait each other, so they will run almost at the same time. Infact, **your code creates an endless/infinite loop without enough wait**(infact it is 1sec. cause you cal run again after the last fadeTo, which has 1 sec fade effect). I think it will lock the browser also.

So break the chain, try to align the function calls in some manner using the callback functions in the fadeTo. Do realize that you only use callback function just for the last fade effect not after the whole run method!. Do not think that you chain the effect just by writing them line under another!

Another tiny problem might be a ";" at the end of last line after run():

```
$(".fade#f6").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() { run() });
```

Add ; after run():

```
$(".fade#f6").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() { run();});
```